# How can I record a screen or region in a browser in a good quality without using soft or plug-ins?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, mozilla, recordrtc

I already used **RecordRTC**, but I had to abandon this decision, because I was getting videos with low quality and small fps. I tried change the options (videoBitsPerSecond, frameInterval) to improve quality, but nothing helped. Maybe I was not competent enough on this issue, but searches on this topic were futile.

If solution isn't exist, I'll look in universal plug-ins direction. Tell me what is better to use in a plugin to record a screen or region in good quality.

Comment: What do you mean by "screen or region"?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the screen?

Comment: I mean whole screen or area of the screen
I tried canvas.captureStream() with html2canvas

Answer (score 1):

Presently only Firefox supports [Screen Capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-capture/) at `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`. You can try testing various constraints at the Firefox implementation for screen, application, and window at [getUserMedia Test Page](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html).

Comment: What is the issue you are having using `canvas.captureStream()`? What exactly are you trying to capture? HTML or an image?

Comment: Issue is bad quality and brake record.<br>
I tried to capture the <canvas> which be drawn with html2canvas.

Comment: @ДаниилЖенихов What is "brake record"? You can use `canvas.captureStream()` to capture the `<canvas>` element

Comment: I already have said that I used canvas.captureStreeam() and I got bad video (low quality and low FPS)

Comment: _"I already have said that I used canvas.captureStreeam() and I got bad video (low quality and low FPS)"_ Can you post the code that you tried at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <pre>var stream = canvas.captureStream(60);
var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);</pre>

Comment: @ДаниилЖенихов Can you include the full code at Question so that we can reproduce the issue you are describing?

Comment: What is expected result of `return`ing `setTimeout()` at `return setTimeout(looper, 500)`?

Comment: Nothing is expected:/

Comment: What frame rate per second are you trying to render at recorded media? What is requirement?

Comment: Sufficient, so that the record does not lag

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried at Question?

Comment: Not certain if it possible to have absolutely no lag when drawing an image of a `<video>` to `<canvas>`

Comment: Yes, I think the same, but if you try my example from pastebin, you'll get awful video. So I am looking for another way to record screen or improve that

Comment: @ДаниилЖенихов Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: What is the issue with the recorded video?